# Combining two arrays and transformation using Jolt

Tags: jolt

I am having a tough time using Jolt mapping trying to transform the input to the necessary form

Input JSON

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Alcohol",
      "collection_id": 123,
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "Tax",
          "property_id": "00001"
        },
        {
          "name": "Expenditure",
          "property_id": "00002"
        }
      ],
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "alcohol_tax",
          "attribute_id": "00011"
        },
        {
          "name": "alcohol_expenditure",
          "attribute_id": "00022"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Output JSON

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Alcohol",
        "collection_id": 123,
        "details": [{
                "property_name": "Tax",
                "property_id": "00001",
                "attribute_id": "00011"
            },
            {
                "property_name": "Expenditure",
                "property_id": "00002",
                "attribute_id": "00022"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried a couple of ways to combine the arrays using a few rules but with little success.

One of the rules

```json
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "name": "&1.name",
          "collection_id": "&1.collection_id",
          "attributes": {
            "*": {
              "attribute_id": "&1.attribute_id[]"
            }
          },
          "properties": {
            "*": {
              "name": "&1.myname[]",
              "property_id": "&1.property_id[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}]
```

is adding all the attributes and properties to all the collections.I do not know why this happens as I thought &1.property_id[] would only add items in that particular collection to the array and not all collections. Any help/clues on why this is happening would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See solution below:

- `[0]` creates the wrapping array
- `[&1]` uses the position of the respective arrays so the results are combined in `details` the important part is wrapping square brackets so its treated as array rather than literal.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "name": "[0].name",
          "collection_id": "[0].collection_id",
          "attributes": {
            "*": {
              "attribute_id": "[0].details.[&1].attribute_id"
            }
          },
          "properties": {
            "*": {
              "name": "[0].details.[&1].name",
              "property_id": "[0].details.[&1].property_id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Produces the following:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Alcohol",
    "collection_id": 123,
    "details": [
      {
        "attribute_id": "00011",
        "name": "Tax",
        "property_id": "00001"
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "00022",
        "name": "Expenditure",
        "property_id": "00002"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```